Simple fluid modeling in Modelica 4.0.0 (2024), problems with media declaration
I am trying to use the Modelica Media library for a first, simple thermo-fluid modeling system:

I have problems with the media definition i think. I am stuck at the following error message:
Expected medium to be a component, but found package instead.
I have copy pasted the model code below, I tried to copy example models media definition for this model.
model heatend_3d_printing

 extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
   replaceable package medium =
      Modelica.Media.CompressibleLiquids.LinearWater_pT_Ambient
     constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;
extends Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Media.Medium;
 import Modelica.Units.Conversions.from_degC;
 import Modelica.Units;
 
parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_amb =from_degC(20);
parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Pressure p_inc = 500000;

  Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Sources.PressureIncrease pressureIncrease(medium = medium,T(fixed = true, start = T_amb))annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-48, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k = p_inc)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Sources.Ambient ambient(medium = medium,T(fixed = true, start = T_amb))  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 2}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Sources.Ambient ambient1(medium = medium,T(fixed = true, start = T_amb))  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {16, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Components.Pipe pipe annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-16, 2}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedHeatFlow fixedHeatFlow(Q_flow = 10, alpha = 0.5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-28, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
connect(ambient.flowPort, pressureIncrease.flowPort_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-70, 2}, {-58, 2}}, color = {255, 0, 0}));
connect(pressureIncrease.flowPort_b, pipe.flowPort_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-38, 2}, {-26, 2}}, color = {255, 0, 0}));
connect(pipe.flowPort_b, ambient1.flowPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-6, 2}, {6, 2}}, color = {255, 0, 0}));
connect(fixedHeatFlow.port, pipe.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-18, 44}, {-16, 44}, {-16, 12}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
annotation(
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, 60}, {40, -20}})));
end heatend_3d_printing;


I wanted to simulate the system with a custom fluid before, but went back to try if a library medium is working, but I couldnt get that to work either.
Tried to copy from different fluid model examples from OMEdit.

The problem is that you are using the wrong fluid component library (in my opinion). The medium models in Modelica.Media are not supported by Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow which, I reckon, is only kept in the Modelica Standard Library to support old models using it.
You should use the Modelica.Fluid library components instead. Although the learning curve is steeper, you'll be rewarded with more options, a library that is compatible with many other Modelica libraries, and more available support online.
Also, if you don't mind 'stepping out' of the Modelica Standard Library, I will highly recommend that you use Modelica Buildings Library which is available directly from OMEdit. It is compatible with Modelica.Fluid and Modelica.Media and it will be much easier get your pump/pipe model to work.

Thank you for the information. I start building with the newer library now.

I would also normally recommend using Modelica.Fluid as in the answer by Rene Just Nielsen, but if you want to use Modelcia.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow it is possible as follows:
model heatend_3d_printing

 extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
parameter Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Media.Medium medium=Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Media.Water();
 import Modelica.Units.Conversions.from_degC;
 import Modelica.Units;

parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_amb =from_degC(20);
parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Pressure p_inc = 500000;

  Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Sources.PressureIncrease pressureIncrease(medium = medium,T(fixed = true, start = T_amb))
                                                                                                                          annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-48, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k = p_inc)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
    Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Sources.Ambient ambient(medium = medium,
      constantAmbientTemperature=T_amb)                                      annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 2}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Sources.Ambient ambient1(medium = medium,
      constantAmbientTemperature=T_amb)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {16, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Components.Pipe pipe(medium = medium) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-16, 2}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedHeatFlow fixedHeatFlow(Q_flow = 10, alpha = 0.5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-28, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation 
connect(ambient.flowPort, pressureIncrease.flowPort_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-70, 2}, {-58, 2}}, color = {255, 0, 0}));
connect(pressureIncrease.flowPort_b, pipe.flowPort_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-38, 2}, {-26, 2}}, color = {255, 0, 0}));
connect(pipe.flowPort_b, ambient1.flowPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-6, 2}, {6, 2}}, color = {255, 0, 0}));
connect(fixedHeatFlow.port, pipe.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-18, 44}, {-16, 44}, {-16, 12}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
annotation(
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, 60}, {40, -20}})));
end heatend_3d_printing;

The important changes are:

The medium is a record parameter (it is a replaceable package in Modelica.Fluid)
There was a weird extends-clause
The ambient has a different parameter for ambient temperature, it is not a variable with start-value
The medium must also be propagated to the pipe; I don't know if it is possible to simplify that in OMEdit

